# Pass password in a hash table Django

Tags: python, django, hash

I am pretty new in Django. I built a website where you can create a user and share posts. My question is how can I pass the password in a hash table when the user registers to the website instead of plain text? I have tried to use make_password but when I was monitoring the protocol on Wireshark I saw the password (I am using the Django built-in User module):
[Wireshark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4QmIn.png)

Comment: If the password is stored in db as a hash string then this is not an issue with Django. Your communication with the backend needs to be SSL-crypted (using https protocol) to avoid the plain text communication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending an encrypted password referes to the communication between client and server. Django (server side) has little to do with that. Either use a SSL (https) connection or - I don't know if this is common practice - encrypt via javascript on the client before sending.

Comment: @itay You are welcome. Please mark the answer as accepted if you think it answers your question.